# Multiple If else in Sql Server Function return error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-function

I am trying to get a unique id number and i have wrote the following SQL Server function to do it. I will give the function the ID of the current admin and it will be on the first digit on the left. Now i want it to return a very unique number only. I have used multiple if so that there shouldn't be a match. I want that when there is no orderid in the table orderdetailstb. And if there is it should +1.

```
USE [ResturantManagementSystem]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[we]    Script Date: 11/11/2016 11:48:59 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
create FUNCTION [dbo].[UniqueOrderId] (@currentAdminid int)
RETURNS int
AS BEGIN
declare @UniqueOrderId int
if (select orderid from OrderDetailsTB) is null
return (select concat(left(@currentAdminid,1),CONVERT(int,getdate(),112),right('1',1)) from Admin)
else
if
(select max(CONVERT(int,getdate(),112)) from OrderDetailsTB)>CONVERT(int,getdate(),112)
return (select concat(left(@currentAdminid,1),CONVERT(int,getdate(),112),right('1',1)) from Admin)
else
return (select concat(left(@currentAdminid,1),CONVERT(int,getdate(),112),right(select max(orderid)+1 from OrderDetailsTB),3) from Admin)
return @UniqueOrderId
END
```

the problem is its giving error at

```
return (select concat(left(@currentAdminid,1),CONVERT(int,getdate(),112),right(select max(orderid)+1 from OrderDetailsTB),3) from Admin)
```

the error is

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure UniqueOrderId, Line 12 Incorrect
>   syntax near the keyword 'select'. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1,
>   Procedure UniqueOrderId, Line 12 Incorrect syntax near ')'.

How can i do it and if it is appropriate for me to use a function or should i move it towards a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
create FUNCTION [dbo].[UniqueOrderId] (@currentAdminid int)
RETURNS int
AS BEGIN
declare @UniqueOrderId int
if (select orderid from OrderDetailsTB) is null
return (select concat(left(@currentAdminid,1),CONVERT(int,getdate(),112),right('1',1)) from Admin)
else
if
(select max(CONVERT(int,getdate(),112)) from OrderDetailsTB)>CONVERT(int,getdate(),112)
return (select concat(left(@currentAdminid,1),CONVERT(int,getdate(),112),right('1',1)) from Admin)
else
return (select concat(left(@currentAdminid,1),CONVERT(int,getdate(),112)
       ,right(maxOrderId,3)) 
        from Admin
        cross apply (select max(orderid)+1 from OrderDetailsTB) ds(maxOrderId)

        )
return @UniqueOrderId
END
```

The idea is to use `outer` or `cross` apply in order to transform inline `select` statement:

```
return (select concat(left(@currentAdminid,1),CONVERT(int,getdate(),112),right(select max(orderid)+1 from OrderDetailsTB),3) from Admin)
```

to:

```
return (select concat(left(@currentAdminid,1),CONVERT(int,getdate(),112)
       ,right(maxOrderId,3)) 
        from Admin
        cross apply (select max(orderid)+1 from OrderDetailsTB) ds(maxOrderId)

        )
```

Comment: Side note: `(select max(CONVERT(int,getdate(),112)) from OrderDetailsTB)>CONVERT(int,getdate(),112)` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sorry, that was meant as a comment to the question.

Comment: Well i want that everyday a new code needs to be generated.

Comment: in the end you have put ds? what is that for?

Comment: This is just alias that we are giving to the `cross apply` data - you can put anything you want

Comment: ok it is working but there is a problem is that after executing 2 times. it saying the subquery is returning more then one value. i tried distinct still

select  concat(left(1,1),CONVERT(int,getdate(),112)
       ,right(maxOrderId,3)) 
        from sampledb
        cross apply (select max(orderid)+1 from sampledb) ds(maxOrderId)